# (random) in biwascheme scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

To practice SICP problems on scheme , I am using the online scheme interpreter at repl.it, which is by biwascheme. But the thing is there is no `(random n)`function, when I do `(random 10)` it shows error, is there some basic workaround so that I can include `(random n)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `random-integer`:

```
(random-integer 10)
;=> 3
```

Since it works exactly how SICP wants its `random` we can alias the name for convenience.

```
(define random random-integer)
(random 10)
;=> 5
```

If you keep on working on the online editor, you can just keep that definition in the top of the editor buffer and you should be set!

The BiwaScheme [docs](https://www.biwascheme.org/doc/sicp.html) recommend also adding the following definitions:

```
(define nil '())
(define true #t)
(define false #f)
(define (random n)
  (random-integer n))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @NKN: well it's also unclear what was specifically lacking in my post but I added a little something.

Comment: @NKN Canned comments like yours are best reserved for users with less than 100 rep. Higher-rep users deserve better than cut-and-paste comments.

Comment: The comment is not cut-and-paste, it is created by SO automatically. When you get more than 2000 rep, you will be able to use such automatic commenting. Anyways, that is not a big deal. Happy new year.